# Cannot implicitly convert fileinfo[] to string[] in c#

Tags: c#, file

I have this line in c# that I need to modify, currently it is working fine

```
 string[] UploadFilesList = new DirectoryInfo(UploadFolder)
         .GetFiles()
         .Select(o => o.Name.Replace(".txt", ""))
         .ToArray();
```

I am not the one who wrote this code. what I want to do is **not** to replace .txt with anything.

so I did this

```
string[] UploadFilesList = new DirectoryInfo(UploadFolder)
        .GetFiles()
        .Select(o => o)
        .ToArray();
```

but getting this error

> Cannot implicitly convert fileinfo[] to string[]  in c#

I changed the code again to

```
string[] UploadFilesList = new DirectoryInfo(UploadFolder)
        .GetFiles()
        .ToArray();
```

but still same error, how to fix this?

Comment: `.Select(o => o)`  should be `Select(o => o.Name)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first code snippet, you are **selecting file name** of each file and then replacing the extension.

In your second and third code snippet, you are getting all files from `DirectoryInfo` and trying to store it in the `string[]`, but

> [`DirectoryInfo().GetFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=net-6.0#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_GetFiles) returns an array of type [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-6.0)

Because of this reason you are getting an error *Cannot implicitly convert fileinfo[] to string[]*

---

If you want an array of name of upload files, then try below,

```
string[] UploadFilesList = new DirectoryInfo(UploadFolder)
           .GetFiles()          //Provide list of files from given. directory
           .Select(x => x.Name) //Select only Name from each FileInfo. Do not replace an extension
           .ToArray();          //Convert to an array.
```

Answer (score 1):

the compiler is telling you that your are trying to store Files in an array of strings which is not possible, to get an array of strings just select the Name property instead of all the File.

.select(o=>o.name)
.toArray();